# Kotlin Concurrency: Any standard function to run code in a Lock?

Tags: multithreading, kotlin, synchronization, locking

I've been searching for a function that takes an object of type [`Lock`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html)
and runs a block of code with that lock taking care of locking and also unlocking.

I'd implement it as follows:

```
fun <T : Lock> T.runLocked(block: () -> Unit) {
    lock()
    try {
        block()
    } finally {
        unlock()
    }
}
```

Used like this:

```
val l = ReentrantLock()
l.runLocked {
    println(l.isLocked)
}

println(l.isLocked)
//true
//false
```

Anything available like this? I could only find the [`synchronized`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/synchronized.html) function which cannot be used like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for [`withLock`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.concurrent/java.util.concurrent.locks.-lock/with-lock.html), which has the exact [implementation](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/1.2.0/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/concurrent/Locks.kt#L30) you've written yourself, except it has a generic parameter for the result of the block instead of the receiver type.

You can find other concurrency related methods of the standard library [here](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.concurrent/index.html), in the `kotlin.concurrent` package.